# _byteswap_ulong in Golang

Tags: go

What is the equivalent of _byteswap_ulong in Golang?
Does it exist as a package?

I tried to use the binary package and play with the reader, but couldn't get it working. I need to swap bytes in a uint64 variable.

Input is 2832779. Output should be 8b392b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @David said, use the [binary.ByteOrder](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#ByteOrder) type

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    value := make([]byte, 4)

    // need to know the byte ordering ahead of time
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(value, 0x12345678)

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", value)

    fmt.Printf("Big Endian Representation, 0x%X\n", binary.BigEndian.Uint32(value))
    fmt.Printf("Little Endian Representation, 0x%X\n", binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(value))
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/Fb6kDPmc_9)

This will output:

```
[]byte{0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12}
Big Endian Representation, 0x78563412
Little Endian Representation, 0x12345678
```

These are the big-endian and little-endian representations on a little-endian server.

Answer (score 2):

The package encoding/binary has a ByteOrder type
http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#ByteOrder

```
binary.LittleEndian
```

and

```
binary.BigEndian
```

Let you swap to different orders.

It's not exactly the same as it doesn't just swap bytes.  But may get you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Golang 1.9 added `ReverseBytes` function family in package `math/bits`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/bits"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%x", bits.ReverseBytes32(2832779))
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/VqFc4Zk3F3w)